# About 'more general case'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A relation is often considered to be a more general case of a property

I don't fully understand. Is it to say *a relation is a case of a property* ? then what's *a more general case*?

Comment: From an article in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28philosophy%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it means that a relation is a property lacking strictness, loosely defined. But it's just a guess. I have no proof and I am not a native either.

For example, if you say that "A is taller than B", A has the property of being taller than B, but you do not know exactly how tall A is, because this is dependent on B.

Answer (score 1):

I think it becomes clearer when stated the other way around:  "A property is a more specific type of relation."  In other words, a relation is a general-purpose category of items, like "vehicle"; a property is a specific type of relation, like "car" is a type of vehicle.  All cars are vehicles, and all properties are relations; but not all vehicles are cars, and not all relations are properties.

Comment: Here, property > relation : [ For generality we will also take properties to include relations like being taller than and lying between](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/). I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence refers to the word *general* as in *less specific*. An item can have measurable properties while relating to other items through comparisons.